# Android native browser having issues with sencha

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch

I have an existing app build in **sencha** 2.0 with ExtJS version 1.1.1. It is working fine in my Galaxy S3 4.1.2 version. The application loads successfully both in Chrome and S3 native browser.

When I install the same application in Galaxy S4 (VERSION 4.2.2), few features are not working in Android native browser. eg: the sencha drop down , scrolling, etc. not working. But it works fine in Chrome for the same device.

I would like to know if any settings/configuration needs to be done in the app to work fine in the Android native browser 4.2.2. I host the app in a Tomcat server and browse it from the device browser.

Does ExtJS 1.1.1 need to be upgraded for android 4.2.2 ? Things are working fine in 4.1.2 version.
 Issue is observed in the galaxy s4 default browser. 
Thanks

Comment: Can someone help please?

Comment: Same application works fine in android 4.3 galaxy s4 browser.